# Is there a method to post form data from one url to another url, and then render the template based on the form data

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to create a simple one item product store, in which customers would go to a product page and choose the quantity they would like to purchase in a form. After completing the form, I would then like for it to redirect to the checkout page and render the quantity they chose. Is there a simple way to do this? At the moment, I am posting the form data to the product page url and then redirecting the user to the checkout page, however I am unsure how to access that data.

```
def proxy_detail(request, proxy_slug):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.AddProxyAmountForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            number_of_proxies = int(cd['number_of_proxies'])
            return redirect('payment:checkout')
    else:
        add_proxy_form = forms.AddProxyAmountForm()
        proxy_product = get_object_or_404(models.ProxyProduct, slug = proxy_slug)
        return render(request, 'shop/product/proxy_detail.html', {'proxy_product' : proxy_product, 'add_proxy_form' : add_proxy_form })
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried at the moment? Thanks!

Comment: This is currently what i am doing, im posting the form to the product page, and then redirecting to the checkout page, however I need to access the variable number_of_proxies on the checkout page

Answer (score 0):

Its not an exact answer but I am new here so I can't really comment :p

Anyways, I think in your view, what you can do is, get the data in a variable and pass it as a context to render another page.

```
def viewname(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        #your logic to save here
        context = {variableOfInterest : request.POST.valueOfInterest} #considering you are getting it from the form
        return render(request, "redirected.html", context)
```